# Why isn't my code terminating within a loop when checking for 'exit' string?

Tags: c, arrays, system-calls, c-strings, procedural-programming

My program is supposed to exit when the user types in exit similar to how its done in a shell. First I checked online to see if syscall could be called in a loop, but then I noticed the indices of the characters in the array are wrong. Why are these changing; when I ran the program and typed in exit I had my program shoot out the 3rd index for testing purposes and it returned 'e'. So I thought it might've been flipped and flipped all values and my exit still did not work. Any thoughts on what the underlying issue may be?

```
  #include <stdio.h>

//Abstract: This program runs a script to emulate shell behavior
#define MAX_BIN_SIZE 100
int main() {      //Memory allocation
 char * entry[MAX_BIN_SIZE];
  while(1)
  {

   printf("msh>");

   fgets(entry,MAX_BIN_SIZE,stdin); //Getting user input


   if(entry[0]=='t' &&  entry[1]=='i' && entry[2]=='x' && entry[3]=='e')
        {
                //printf("Exiting");
                exit(0); //exit(system call)
                break;
                printf("Inside of exit");
        }
   printf("msh> you typed %s %c %c %c %c",entry,entry[3],entry[2],entry[1],entry[0]); //returning user input                                            
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did entry contain when you looked with a debugger? You test for it having 'tixe', it probably didnt contain that. (And what BLUEPIXY said)

Comment: `char * entry[MAX_BIN_SIZE];` --> `char entry[MAX_BIN_SIZE];`

Comment: You should have gotten some compiler warnings hinting at where this code is wrong. Read them. They're important.

Comment: It's definitely not backwards.  Maybe you had some leading spaces?   You should check the return of fgets() and after it do: `printf("|%s|\n", entry);` to see.

Comment: `char *entry[MAX_BIN_SIZE]` would make an array of pointers, which fgets will fill as bytes, then you try to compare that against "tixe" as pointers.

Comment: You seem fundamentally confused regarding types, which indicates that you're probably guessing rather than reading a book and doing the exercises... If you'd rather learn the less troublesome way, feel free to ask for advice regarding a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment, but @lundman is correct. I don't think you need to create a pointer to entry. Also, you are checking for "exit" in the reverse order. I tried and edited the code; this seems to work:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

//Abstract: This program runs a script to emulate shell behavior
#define MAX_BIN_SIZE 100
int main()
{      //Memory allocation
    char entry[MAX_BIN_SIZE];
    while(1)
    {

        printf("msh>");

        fgets(entry,MAX_BIN_SIZE,stdin); //Getting user input


        if(entry[0]=='e' &&  entry[1]=='x' && entry[2]=='i' && entry[3]=='t')
        {

            printf("Inside of exit");//printf("Exiting");
            exit(0); //exit(system call)
        }
        printf("msh> you typed %s %c %c %c %c\n",entry,entry[3],entry[2],entry[1],entry[0]); //returning user input
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `string.h` and then simplify do `if(strstr(entry, "exit"))` to see if exit is included in the entry string, if you need the word exit to be at the start then check if the result of strstr points to the same place as entry. Just seems to be a bit cleaner.